# how to remove Google Webmaster Core Web Vitals error

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, linode, core-web-vitals

I use PageSpeed Insights and geting a score of 90+ for mobile and desktop. But when using Google Webmaster Tools the Core Web Vitals information shows that LCP and FID failed.
I use Newspaper WordPress themes, and Linode Cloud hosting 20$ package.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear this for you. The Core Web Vitals report shows how your pages perform based on real world usage data. It also known as field data.

The data used for this report comes from the Chrome User Experience (CrUX) report. The CrUX report is powered by aggregated user experience metrics from actual users visiting your website.

This report is currently based on 3 metrics:

**Largest Contentful Paint (LCP)**: a loading performance measurement, should occur during the first 2.5 seconds of the page loading.

**First Input Delay (FID)**: an interactivity measurement, should be less than 100 milliseconds.

**Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)**: a visual stability measurement, should be less than 0.1.

Other metrics relating the core web vitals include:

**First contentful paint (FCP)**: the time from when the user requests the URL until the browser renders the first visible element in the URL. Closely relating to the FID and LCP.

So, try to optimize your images or videos you have on your website properly and then use caching plugin like WP Rocket with proper settings.

For more details and clear understanding you can check this [reference](https://www.oradmt.com/how-to-fix-core-web-vitals-issues-lcp-cls-fid) and this [reference](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520?hl=en).